Why do you need to specify the ReturnType twice if you return an object
Suppose I have a type like this for a function:
type FN = () => { test: 1 };

but here is its implementation with the wrong return type:
const fn: FN = () => ({ test: 1, test2: 2 });

TypeScript doesn't recognize this as an error
But if you explicitly specify the return type in the implementation (once again), for example like this:
const fn: FN = (): ReturnType<FN> => ({ test: 1, test2: 2 });

then TypeScript will throw an error:
Type "{ test: 1; test2: number; }" is not assignable to type "{ test: 1; }".

Is this a bug in TypeScript? Or, if this is intended behavior, then what's the point?

Key term to research: excess property checks. { test: 1, test2: 2 } is a valid { test: 1 } (not { test: number }?); test2 won't be accessible via that interface anyway. So fn is compatible with FN.

@jonrsharpe Could there be a way to force an excess property check on a function return type without explicitly specifying the return type in the implementation?

This is not a bug in TypeScript; it's by design. Here's why:

Type Inference vs. Type Checking:  TypeScript excels at inferring types. When you write:
const fn: FN = () => ({ test: 1, test2: 2 }); 

TypeScript infers that fn returns an object of type { test: 1, test2: number }. While technically broader, this is still compatible with the FN type.

Interfaces and Contracts: The purpose of a type like FN or an interface is to establish a contract. It defines the expected shape of the return value. By failing to explicitly specify the return type in the implementation, you risk an unintended mismatch down the line.


When you add the explicit return type declaration:
const fn: FN = (): ReturnType<FN> => ({ test: 1, test2: 2 });

You are effectively saying, "This function must return an object that has only the test: 1 property." This highlights the discrepancy between the implementation's return value and the stricter contract.
